# How to Load Angular 6 Routes in Electron?

Tags: angular, routes, electron, angular6, angular-routing

I'm using angular 6 in electron ng serve web all routes working fine but when I run in ng run electron routing doest work. I'm using routerLink my code is

> ```
> <a routerLink="user" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="icon-user icons"></i> Users</a>
> ```

and in app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

> `{ path: 'user', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }`
>       `@NgModule({   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],   exports: [RouterModule] })`

I don't know how it works! also I tried href but doest fruitful.
thanks

Comment: Try to add a period in front of the slash in src/index.html `<base href="./">`

Comment: @Suryan I tried this.